# How can I generate XML from the JSON Data using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, json

I have the JSON data something like below:

```
{
    "#data": [
        {
            "nid": "814",
            "type": "resource",
            "language": "",
            "uid": "125",
            "status": "1",
            "title": "title 1",
            "description": "description 1",
            "rating": "5",
            "picture": "" 
        },
        {
            "nid": "814",
            "type": "resource",
            "language": "",
            "uid": "125",
            "status": "1",
            "title": "title 2",
            "description": "description 2",
            "rating": "3.5",
            "picture": "" 
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to build XML out of this something like below:

```
<node title="title 1" type="resource" rating="5">
        <description>description 1</description>
</node>
<node title="title 2" type="resource" rating="3.5">
 <description>description 2</description>
</node>
```

I don't want to deserialize the JSON data, but I need to fetch only few elements and build the XML object. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: If you don't want to deserialize the Json data you'll need to parse it. Are you sure it's worth the effort?

Comment: Hi Paolo, If I deserialize the json data, I will get all the data elements which I don't want. I want to fetch only few elements and exclude rest of the thing. In the above example, I have used only few elements, but in actual it has got more data. Please suggest how I can do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize it into a c# object then xml serialize it. Easiest way

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to deserialize it, unless you want to do some ugly string parsing.